# Switching between shared buffers in emacs gdb mode without mouse (in text-terminal)

Tags: linux, terminal, emacs, gcc, gdb

From the documentation link here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-GDB-Buffers.html

> When gdb-many-windows is non-nil, the locals buffer shares its window with the registers buffer, just like breakpoints and threads buffers. To switch from one to the other, click with mouse-1 on the relevant button in the header line.

I am in the pure text-based terminal and don't have a mouse. Is there a built-in keyboard shortcut to switch between those two buffers (without having to add any extra configurations in init file)?

Either keyboard shortcut or command (like M-x ...) is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be a simple <kbd>tab</kbd>. The source [gdb-mi.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/gdb-mi.el) has a defvar for [gdb-locals-mode-map](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/gdb-mi.el#L4181)  which seems to in place in the locals buffer. Look for use of the symbol `header-line` which is what the feature is called, and then symbols `gdb-locals-buffer`, `gdb-locals-mode`.